# Errors with python-openid and Google Apps Federated Login

Tags: python, openid, trac, google-apps, python-openid

### UPDATE

I managed to get it working although I'm not quite sure why ;) It seems like python-openid uses a POST-request to issue the openid mode=associate and for some reason Google doesn't like that. When I patched python-openid to use a GET-request instead everything worked fine. I'll continue my investigation and update this post when I have more information. Below is the diff for my change.

```
--- python-openid-2.2.1.orig/openid/consumer/consumer.py
+++ python-openid-2.2.1/openid/consumer/consumer.py
@@ -229,6 +229,20 @@
     # Process response in separate function that can be shared by async code.
     return _httpResponseToMessage(resp, server_url)

+def makeKVGet(request_message, server_url):
+    """Make a Direct Request to an OpenID Provider and return the
+    result as a Message object.
+
+    @raises openid.fetchers.HTTPFetchingError: if an error is
+        encountered in making the HTTP post.
+
+    @rtype: L{openid.message.Message}
+    """
+    # XXX: TESTME
+    resp = fetchers.fetch(request_message.toURL(server_url))
+
+    # Process response in separate function that can be shared by async code.
+    return _httpResponseToMessage(resp, server_url)

 def _httpResponseToMessage(response, server_url):
     """Adapt a POST response to a Message.
@@ -682,6 +696,7 @@
         return True

     _makeKVPost = staticmethod(makeKVPost)
+    _makeKVGet = staticmethod(makeKVGet)

     def _checkSetupNeeded(self, message):
         """Check an id_res message to see if it is a
@@ -1258,7 +1273,7 @@
             endpoint, assoc_type, session_type)

         try:
-            response = self._makeKVPost(args, endpoint.server_url)
+            response = self._makeKVGet(args, endpoint.server_url)
         except fetchers.HTTPFetchingError, why:
             oidutil.log('openid.associate request failed: %s' % (why[0],))
             return None
```

### Old question, preserved for context

I've been trying desperately to get the [trac-authopenid](http://bitbucket.org/Dalius/authopenid-plugin/) plugin to work but with no luck.

We use Google Apps Premier at work so I'm trying to get openid auth working with that. I think I've set up all the required stuff (XRDS and such) as far as google is concerned and I've gotten it to work fine with apache2 + [mod-auth-openid](http://trac.butterfat.net/public/mod_auth_openid) as well as using it on other sites (SO for example).

But I can't seem to get it to work with trac-authopenid. I get redirected (via a form post, not a redirect as usual) to Google where I get to log in but when I return the plugin simply states that validation failed.

If i turn on debug logging I get this (I've replaced our domain name with example.com)

```
2010-01-27 12:21:15,811 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: beginning OpenID authentication.
2010-01-27 12:21:16,866 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: kvToSeq warning: Line 1 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
2010-01-27 12:21:16,866 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: kvToSeq warning: Line 2 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
2010-01-27 12:21:16,866 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: kvToSeq warning: Line 3 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
    ... snipped, repeats until line 9...
2010-01-27 12:21:16,867 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: openid.associate request failed: bad status code from server https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=
2010-01-27 12:21:16,868 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: _get_trust_root href: /trac
2010-01-27 12:21:16,868 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: _get_trust_root abs_href: https://developer.example.com/trac
2010-01-27 12:21:16,868 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: _get_trust_root href: /trac
2010-01-27 12:21:16,868 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: _get_trust_root abs_href: https://developer.example.com/trac
2010-01-27 12:21:16,869 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8 using stateless mode.
2010-01-27 12:21:18,068 Trac[main] DEBUG: Dispatching <Request "GET u'/openidprocess'">
2010-01-27 12:21:18,075 Trac[session] DEBUG: Retrieving session for ID '25a842642693232301aad341'
2010-01-27 12:21:18,078 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: Error attempting to use stored discovery information: <openid.consumer.consumer.TypeURIMismatch: Required ty
2010-01-27 12:21:18,078 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: Attempting discovery to verify endpoint
2010-01-27 12:21:18,078 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: Performing discovery on http://example.com/openid?id=113663311178245814720
2010-01-27 12:21:18,121 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: Received id_res response from https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8 using association AOQobUefon
2010-01-27 12:21:18,121 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: Using OpenID check_authentication
2010-01-27 12:21:18,121 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: op_endpoint
2010-01-27 12:21:18,121 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: claimed_id
2010-01-27 12:21:18,121 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: identity
2010-01-27 12:21:18,122 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: return_to
2010-01-27 12:21:18,122 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: response_nonce
2010-01-27 12:21:18,122 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: assoc_handle
2010-01-27 12:21:18,576 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: kvToSeq warning: Line 1 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
2010-01-27 12:21:18,577 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: kvToSeq warning: Line 2 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
2010-01-27 12:21:18,577 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: kvToSeq warning: Line 3 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n
    ... snipped, repeats until line 9...
2010-01-27 12:21:18,578 Trac[authopenid] DEBUG: check_authentication failed: bad status code from server https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8: 501
```

I tried writing some code directly against the [python-openid](http://openidenabled.com/python-openid/) library in order to narrow it down a little but I'm clueless. I've been able to reproduce the error with this code snippet:

```
from openid.store.memstore import MemoryStore
from openid.consumer import consumer

session = { 'id' : 'foobar' }
store = MemoryStore()
consumer = consumer.Consumer(session, store)
consumer.begin('https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com')
```

Which consistently outputs

```
kvToSeq warning: Line 1 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Not Implemented</H1>\n<H2>Error 501</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
kvToSeq warning: Line 2 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Not Implemented</H1>\n<H2>Error 501</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
kvToSeq warning: Line 3 does not contain a colon: '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Implemented</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Not Implemented</H1>\n<H2>Error 501</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
... snip ...
openid.associate request failed: bad status code from server https://www.google.com/a/example.com/o8/ud?be=o8: 501
```

Some version numbers:

```
Python 2.6.2
trac-authopenid 0.1.6
python-openid 2.2.1
```

I'm at a complete loss and I could really use some help.

Comment: Why https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=example.com instead of https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id ?

Comment: I was going to tell you to submit that patch to http://trac.openidenabled.com/ if it turns out to be necessary, which raises the question: Does your OpenID work on *that* trac installation?

Comment: @keturn: because we use Google Apps Account (or 'hosted' accounts as it's sometimes called) so it's not my personal Google Account. All employees at my company has an account used to access mail, documents etc. See http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/apps/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html

Seems like trac.openidenabled.com delegates uses rpxnow for it's authentication and that works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay.  I don't have an Apps account so I can't test logging in, but I can successfully associate with an apps domain with python-openid 2.2.4.  Here's a little debugging tool for making association requests: http://gist.github.com/288560

Your patch should not have fixed things; [associate requests are always POSTs](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#associations).  And the Ruby library also always POSTs, so unless rpxnow has made some unusual modifications, rpxnow shouldn't work when python-openid fails here.

I was about to ask you about the `openid.store` on your install, but if your minimal example with the MemoryStore reproduces it, that's not it.

I guess the only thing left I have for you is to suggest that you ask Google Apps customer support.

Comment: This is really helpful! Something has changed between 2.2.1 and 2.2.4. Both mine and your code fails on a pristine 2.2.1 but works on 2.2.4. Sweet. 

I've got it working now. Adding ax support to trac-authopenid enabled me to use our official email addresses as trac usernames.  A carefully crafted whitelist ensures that only company accounts can sign in, a default openid + permredirect makes users auto-login when they visit the site. I've got to write a blog entry about this ;)

But I digress. What I meant to say was thanks a lot!

Comment: Got the same issue fixed by updating python-openid to 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you're using Python **2.6.2** with python-openid.  The Requirements section of the README file *currently* only lists Python 2.3, 2.4, or 2.5.  It's good to hear you got it working.